# Recycleview for Firebase nested child unable to show

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to populate view of nested child from a user's rewards, but I am unable to show anything out on my android App. Any advice on how do I proceed with it? Please see below regarding the codes iIhave coded so far.

My model

```
public class myrewards{
 String barImg;

public myrewards()
{

}

public myrewards(String barImg) {
    this.barImg = barImg;
}

public String getBarImg() {
    return barImg;
}

public void setBarImg(String barImg) {
    this.barImg = barImg;
}
}
```

My Viewholder

```
public class RewardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


View mView;

public RewardViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    mView = itemView;
}



public void setRewardDetail(Context ctx, String barImg)
{
    ImageView rImg = mView.findViewById(R.id.rImage);

    Picasso.with(ctx).load(barImg).into(rImg);

}
```

}

My Main Activity

```
public class MyRewardsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = MyRewardsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private RecyclerView rRecycleView;
private DatabaseReference myReward, userRef, voucherRef;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private String userID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_rewards);


    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("My Rewards");

    rRecycleView = findViewById(R.id.my_reward);
    rRecycleView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rRecycleView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    myReward = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child(userID);
    userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child(userID);
    System.out.println("YOUR REWARD= " + myReward);


}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<myrewards, RewardViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<myrewards, RewardViewHolder>
                    (
                         myrewards.class,
                         R.layout.barrewards,
                         RewardViewHolder.class,
                         myReward
                    )
            {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(RewardViewHolder viewHolder, myrewards model, int position) {

                    viewHolder.setRewardDetail(getApplicationContext() ,model.getBarImg());

                }
            };
    rRecycleView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}
}
```

Image shown below:

[image]

I am not sure whether I used the correct way to code as I been using this way to retrieve my other data( which are not nested child) from my database, really appericate any helps and thank you in advance.

Comment: Your Recyclerview adapter is wrong. Check if you are getting data from firebase using log

Comment: Have you tried to use `myReward = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child(userID).child("myreward");`?

Comment: Hello all, i manage to figure out the problem, i used User for my firebaseDatabase instead of Users which i declare in my firebase, thank you so much for the help :)